Azure Data Factory in the body of an API call
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm trying to filter records where the salary is 1 within the last 24 hours from the current date. I attempted both methods, but without success. Please advise me on where I might be going wrong. Also, the API operates on a token-based system, and I'm using Copy activity to achieve this.
enter image description here
enter image description here

You can try the below query like below for filtering.
{
"filters":[
    {"property":"salary","operator":"greaterThanOrEqual","value":0}]
}

If you still it results same, you can try below workaround to achieve your requirement if your target is not an on-premises.

First set a loop using For-each or Until activity which should iterate as per your page size or page id in the URL. Inside for-loop, instead of copy activity, use Dataflow.
For the source of the dataflow, use parameterized REST dataset. provide the value for the dataset parameters.
After the source of the dataflow, add filter transformation. In the filter transformation add your filter logic to get the records which have salary greater than or equal to 0.
Add your target as sink. If it is a Blob storage file, add parameterized dataset. Parameterize the filename. If it is any SQL table, there is no need to parameterize. You can add the same table for every iteration.
In each iteration, the new files will be created with filtered records. After the for-each, use a copy activity to merge all these files into a single file.

